# Overriding hashCode() in eclipse- Java

Tags: java, jakarta-ee, overriding, hashcode

Whenever I override hashcode() using eclipse 'source' menu it generates following code in the class

```
final int prime = 31;
int result = 1;
result = prime * result + ((fieldName1== null) ? 0 : fieldName1.hashCode());
result = prime * result + ((fieldName2== null) ? 0 : fieldName2.hashCode());
```

Could anyone please explain why it is doing all this calculation(multiplication and then addition), why it is not returning simply

```
fieldName.hashCode();
or
fieldName2.hashCode();
```

?

Comment: Try having two or more fields in your class and then generate and see what happens.

Comment: @Zavior this is no duplicate as in the oter question it is asked why not XOR is used. Here it is asked why the calculation is used to create the `hashCode`.

Comment: fair enough, the first answer there does answer this one as well :P

Comment: @darijan I have 15 fields in my class I put just a section of code here coz of readability purpose, although I put Two fields here.

Comment: See also http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11795104/is-the-hashcode-function-generated-by-eclipse-any-good

Answer (score 0):

Multiplying reduces [collisions](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hash_collision).

Please read [Joshua Bloch](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/0321356683)

> The value 31 was chosen because it is an odd prime. If it were even and the multiplication overflowed, information would be lost, as multiplication by 2 is equivalent to shifting. The advantage of using a prime is less clear, but it is traditional. A nice property of 31 is that the multiplication can be replaced by a shift and a subtraction for better performance: 31 * i == (i << 5) - i. Modern VMs do this sort of optimization automatically.

Comment: This doesnt answer his question though

Comment: ok I get that y '31' is chosen but I am asking why we need to do(or y IDE generates) 'all' of this calculation. Please read question for reference.

Comment: By multiplying, bits are left shifted which uses more of the available space of hash codes, reducing collisions.

Comment: As The New Idiot says: it reduces collisions

Answer (score 0):

It is explained [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1145217/why-should-hash-functions-use-a-prime-number-modulus/1147232#1147232).

Basically you use primes in multiplication to have a better distribution of the hash values. Then `HashSet` and `HashMap` work better because they distibute according to the hash value. And badly distributed hash values lead to many collisions.

Answer (score 0):

> why it is not returning simply
>   `fieldName.hashCode()`;
>   or
>   `fieldName2.hashCode()`;

To understand why, you must also examine the implementation of `equals()` and understand the constraints placed on the `hashCode()` implementation.

1. A `hashCode()` implementation must return equal values for objects that compare as equal: if `x.equals(y)` then `x.hashCode() == y.hashCode()`.
2. A *good* `hashCode()` implementation should rarely return the same hash code for objects that do not compare as equal: if `!x.equals(y)` then *often* `x.hashCode() != y.hashCode()`.
3. The `equals()` implementation that Eclipse generated examines both `fileName1` and `filename2`. If either are different for two objects, the method will consider them the two objects to be not equivalent.
4. Therefore a corresponding *good* `hashCode()` implementation should produce different hash code values if either `fileName1` **or** `fileName2` are different.
5. Therefore a corresponding *good* `hashCode()` implementation should use `fileName1.hashCode()` **and** `fileName2.hashCode()`.